# Why would an audio recording acoustics be different for the same codec in a different application?

Tags: multimedia

Environment is as follows

OS: WinXP 
App: Sound Recorder, Audacity, Media Player
Codec: Lame

I typically use Audacity to record, and then export the recording as an mp3.
The issue that arises is this - the export sounds very different from the original recording, depending upon what application the export is played in.

Why does it sound different even though it uses the same Lame codecs?

Comment: What exactly are you recording? And how is it different? Some programs might apply effects like filtering, compression, noise reduction etc. on incoming signals, which can change the sound perceivably.

Comment: It's plain no-frills speech recorded using the Windows Sound Recorder. The difference is in the way it sounds between one application, and another. For instance; Playing the same recording, unmodified, in Audacity makes it sound like the 'empty room echo'.

Comment: So you're not actually recording with Audacity, simply importing an existing recording, and it seems to be applying an echo or reverb effect to it, that doesn't happen when you listen to the recording in other programs? Does it do this with anything you import?

Comment: In another program e.g. Media Player Classic, the recording sounds 'clipped'. Hence my confusion wondering why it sounds different at almost each place.